# iPhone App Crash in iOS 5.1 in iPad 1 & nicely working in iPhone 4 & iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash

I am developing social media application. it works fine with `iPhone4` and `iPhone5`. even it was working fine in `iPad 1` also but last 2-3 days my application not works more then 1 min. my `iPhone4` & `iPhone5` having iOS 6 & `iPad1` has iOS 5.1.

I have checked in instrumental. Its not consuming that much of memory. because my app crash in `HomeViewController`.

can any one have idea, what is the exact problem it is?

Comment: show code at which place it crash.

Comment: what is the meaning of `Its not consuming that much of memory` ?

Comment: @BuntyMadan Madan no Its not consuming that much of memory

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD RATHOD this is randome crash. its not showing any break point. it just stop application.

Comment: Any crash log? try enabling Zombie to track any invalid memory access.

Comment: @rptwsthi thanks, enabling Zombie it working fine.

Comment: But it's not a good approach, you should sort out the problem and then  disable zombie, as enable zombie leads to some serious memory drawbacks.

Comment: Sounds like you use a function, which isn't available in iOS 5.1 like the `Tighten Letter Spacing` or `Attributed Strings`

Answer (score 1):

I think your app crashes because of a memory issue

To confirm that it's a memory issue, sync your device with iTunes,and look in `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/` for a files with `LowMemory` in their name. If you see `(jettisoned)` next to your app name, that confirms it was killed by iOS for using too much memory.

The only other way an app could exit without leaving a crash report is if it [erroneously called `exit()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/).

For more information, see "[Debugging Deployed iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/)", and "[Understanding and Analyzing iOS Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/)".

**EDIT**

what does **jettisoned** means?

It means the process was terminated because iOS needed memory:

> Memory usage of each process is reported in terms of number of memory pages, which as of this writing are 4KB each. *You will see "(jettisoned)" next to the name of any process terminated by iOS to free up memory*. If you see it next to your application's name, that confirms the application was terminated for using too much memory.
>
> [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

I would take a look at that technical note for some additional help. The documentation also points out the Instruments does not measure graphics memory use, and that requires special handling.

Comment: i could not find (jettisoned) any where in ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

Comment: Can you post a picture of your crash report please

Answer (score 0):

try this :

on `Edit Scheme`
select the "`Diagnostics`" tab and click "`Enable Zombie Objects`":  Like..

[image]

Then go to product and profile on xcode menu.
[image]

it runs your application and you get exact information of crash